# Saifur's, Shahin's, Mijan's

Tags: usage, possessives, proper-nouns, names

Some institutes are called Saifur's, Shahin's, Mijan's.

Saifur is a person's name. His language institute reads 'S@ifur's.

My question is why this institute is named with an apostrophe 's' at the end. What grammatical rule is followed here.

When to use them?
What do they mean?
Some more uses, please.
Suppose my name is Naim. I opened an institute called Naim's. Here What does Naim's mean?

Comment: Please add more context. What do you mean by "institutes"? Where are you seeing things like "Saifur's"? Is that the full name, or what people call them when speaking? Please give examples of usage.

Comment: Google suggests that Saifur's is a test prep company in Bangladesh.

Comment: I guess to further clarify my questions, "...use their name like..." - do you mean that their names are **not** "Saifur's" etc., but are instead officially something like "The Saifur Institute"? Then, do you want to know when someone might use this form in referring to a company/institution?

Comment: Or do you mean that they **are** called "Saifur's" etc. and you want to know why they have branded themselves in this way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are describing is a shortening of the possessive, such as *Sammy's baseball*.  In this case, they are indicating a place of business, such as *Sammy's Pizza Parlor"*.  They are further shortening it by neglecting to say the kind of business, so *Sammy's Pizza Parlor* simply becomes *Sammy's*.

It's not as crazy as it might sound.  If there were two pizza parlors in the neighborhood, *Billy's Pizza Parlor* and *Sammy's Pizza Parlor*, when asked where you were going for lunch, you might just respond "I'm going to Billy's."  Everyone would know what you meant, and shortening the name of the restaurant that way would demonstrate familiarity with the neighborhood.

Business names like the ones you describe are trying to advertise to potential customers that they are familiar parts of the local area.

Answer (score 1):

None of those are common, but they're possessives of an understood "place" similar to *chemist's*, *druggist's*, *florist's*, *grocer's* modifying an understood "shop" or "store".